# Tokenize string by each character sequence of each word

Tags: php, regex, string, tokenize

I feel like this could have been asked, but titled differently therefore I cannot find a exact duplicate.

Whats the easiest way to tokenize a string so that each word is tokenized, as well as each sequence of characters in each word? I assume it can be done with a regexp split, but maybe not...

The effect would be....

`Hey you guys`

**TO**

`[H, e, y, He, Hey, y, o, u, yo, you, g, u, y, s, gu, guy, guys]`

The order is not important, as along as the result would have the same effect as above.

Can regexp do this, or is some sort of custom tokenizing in order?

Comment: You can first split into words, then for each word, generate whatever you want. But it seems that you don't want `ou` or `uys`?

Comment: nope, just from the start of the word onwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom tokenizing would be your best bet in this.

```
$inStr = 'Hey you guys';
$tokens = array();
$tokenList = explode(' ',$inStr);
foreach($tokenList as $bigToken) {
    $tokens[] = $bigToken; //take care of individual words
    $tokens = array_merge($tokens, str_split($bigToken)); //take care of single letters
    for($i = 2; $i < strlen($bigToken); $i++) {
        $tokens[] = substr($bigToken, 0, $i); //only need the first element here.
    }
}
print_r($tokens);
```

Here's the working code. http://3v4l.org/gZn8p

Comment: yep, this definitely works, thanks...one edit you can make is replace the two lines in the nested loop to `$tokens[] = substr($bigToken, 0, $i)`...save some operations

Comment: Ill wait till the morning (PST) to accept this, just in case someone else has another idea

Comment: Oh yeah, that would definitely save some operations.